# How do I write an IF statement inside the return function?

Tags: reactjs

This will be part of a checkout screen in an online store, I'm trying to write an if statement inside the return that dictates what will be shown to the user based on whether or not there are products in the cart or not. My browser isn't reading the code, it's just inserting all of the code onto the screen as plain text and I can't figure out what the issue is. Thanks in advance

```
render() { 
        return (
            <div>
            if(this.context.cart.length === 0){
                <div className="emptyCart">
                    <p>Your cart is empty right now, when you're done shopping return here to see it!</p>
                </div>
            }else{
                <div className="cartTotal">
                    <label className="price">Total Price: ${this.getTotal()}</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the conditional operator instead, inside of `{` `}` delimiters (which separates JSX markup from JavaScript expressions).

```
render() {
    return (<div>{
        this.context.cart.length === 0
            ? (
                <div className="emptyCart">
                    <p>Your cart is empty right now, when you're done shopping return here to see it!</p>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div className="cartTotal">
                    <label className="price">Total Price: ${this.getTotal()}</label>
                </div>
            )
    }</div>);
}
```